# Android ListPreference how to change the size of the alert dialog

Tags: android, preference

I can set the button, the icon of the alert dialog.But I don't know how to change the size of the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

try this, just add setlayout() method after show()

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //change width and height.
```

Comment: It likes the custom alert dialog.Your method is feasible,but need me to data loading and persistence.I prefer to change the system layout directly.